# ionic 2 innerHTML missing attribute id

Tags: angular, ionic2

I have a script like this...

ts:

```
export class namaClass{

 content: any;

 constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {

  this.content = [

   {judul: "Judul 1", isi:"<div id='title_1'>Isinya</div>"},

   {judul: "Judul 2", isi:"<div id='title_2'>Isinya</div>"},

  ]

 }

}
```

html:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of content">
 <h3 [innerHTML]="item.judul"></h3>
 <div [innerHTML]="item.isi"></div>
</div>
```

when I try to DOM/inspect element, element id in `[innerHTML]="item.isi"` not show. How to show that id?

Comment: Any related message in the browser console?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer in nothing happend in console, but when i try to inspect the elemnt just like

<h3>Judul 1</h3>
<div>Isinya</div>
<h3>Judul 2</h3>
<div>Isinya</div>

i want like this
<h3>Judul 1</h3>
<div id="title_1">Isinya</div>
<h3>Judul 2</h3>
<div id="title_2">Isinya</div>

Comment: code seems to work fine in online editor https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-rorvvr check your code again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it is :

Component side :

```
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';

constructor(protected _sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}

safeHtml(html) {
  return this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(html);
}
```

Template side :

```
<div *ngFor="let item of content">
 <h3 [innerHTML]="safeHtml(item.judul)"></h3>
 <div [innerHTML]="safeHtml(item.isi)"></div>
</div>
```

Link to : [**WORKING DEMO**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-inner-html)

For more detail : **https://angular.io/guide/security**

Comment: You should not call the sanitizer from view bindings. Call it in code an assign the result to a field and bind to that field instead.

Comment: @VivekDoshi it is working like a charm (: thank you very much sir

Comment: @OmanFathurohman, Glad to here that, will you please also upvote and accept the answer?